# LinkedIn etiquette after an interview/ before starting new position

Tags: interviewing, linkedin

Similar to [What is LinkedIn etiquette before an interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10144/what-is-linkedin-etiquette-before-an-interview) I would like to know if viewing an interviewer or future co-worker's LinkedIn profile after an interview is acceptable, both while waiting for a response from the company and, after accepting an offer, waiting for your first day.

The benefit to doing this before hearing if you have been offered the position or not would be to show that you are still actively interested and researching the company, the benefit to doing this after you have been offered the job would be to get an idea of what kind of background your coworkers have.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a LinkedIn profile means accepting that it will be viewed by others. There is nothing unethical about taking advantage of the tool's features and doing your 'homework', for whatever reason.

From this standpoint, it makes more sense to view an interviewer's profile *before* the interview, assuming of course that you know the interviewer's identify prior to the event. In reality it often happens that you come into the interview 'blind', having very little idea about who will be in the room.

Whatever the case, what matters more is whether and how you use the information you learn from their profile. So before you start looking, think about what question you are trying to answer, or what decision it would help you make.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's **acceptable**.    However, it's also **completely pointless**.

Before an interview, you can at least try to glean some background about your interview's background and interests, but afterwards, it's not going to tell you anything about what will happen.

Comment: If the interviewer is also the hiring manager, then viewing their profile can provide additional useful insight about their background and experience with current employer. This in turn can provide additional input in deciding whether the position reporting to this person would be a good fit for the applicant, as well as with regard to opportunities for advancement.